# How to change font color for only the current page?

Tags: color, afterpage, shipout

As mentioned by the title, I need to change font color for only the current page. After searching the internet, the `afterpage` package seems to be a good choice, as well as `\colorlet{saved}{.}` from the `xcolor` package. Hence the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\colorlet{saved}{.}
\color{yellow}
\afterpage{\color{saved}}

\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

However, color of font in the second page remains unchanged.

Could you please figure why the color stays unchanged, and could you please help me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Does your real use case have a forced page break? if so the answer is easy just put `\color{saved}` after `\clearpage`  or do you want the colour to change at an automatic-page break, possibly mid-paragrarah? That is harder and in general not always possible automatically.

Comment: This could be an XY question, using `\afterpage` *could* be the wrong thing to do from the beginning. What is your greater goal?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It depends. Sometimes a `\clearpage` will be added and thus I could be able to declare color clearly. However, it's hard for me to add such color declaration in automatically process, for example in the toc output process. What if the fact is ensured that no float processing will try to break our color restore mechanism? Or, maybe we could have a try to handle this after the ltx2e layout codes have decided not to build a float page (column)?

Comment: @Johannes_B, Thanks for the reply. The original problem is that I need to change the background color of specific area in the chapter title page. In the very page, a light color of font is therefore needed, and in the following pages, black should be recovered. Do you have any clues?

Comment: Use only the chapter title on a page of its own.

Comment: Or better, don't mess around with colours. It is expensive.

Answer (score 4):

`\afterpage` adds a group. This here works as expected (but I wouldn't rely on it in all cases):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\colorlet{saved}{.}
\color{yellow}
\newcommand\restorecolor{\color{saved}}
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restorecolor}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! It's a shame that I didn't know `\aftergroup` before. However, I guess this could be broke by the floating process?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng this could be broken by _anything_ :-) please read the warnings in the `afterpage` documentation. I wouldn't use it in any production setting. Changing a colour at a page change is such an odd thing to do, is there really no structural change in the document at that point which corresponds to the colour change?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng: As I said: I wouldn't rely on it. I use afterpage only very seldom and very carefully. I only wanted to show why it didn't work in your (simple) example. Like David I find your requirement rather odd and imho there should be something more logical (as you mentioned the titlepage: I would simply use grouping there).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, let me think twice about this. Thank you for the help. : )

Comment: @Ch'enMeng try replacing that `\par` by `\blindtext` .....